# Automating preprocessing of LANDSAT data

Tags: remote-sensing, software-recommendations, landsat

I'm currently enrolled in a remote sensing course, using LANDSAT data.
Part of my course is about **standardizing the scenes based on radiance values**. I assume that because this is such a tedious task, someone has already figured out a way to automate it.

**Are there any tools, Esri or otherwise that will standardize LANDSAT scenes?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With GRASS GIS (http://grass.osgeo.org) you can do these steps:

- Import Landsat imagery in a GRASS database using:

  - bash scripts: see page bottom at http://www.grassbook.org/examples_menu3rd.php
  - python script in GRASS-Wiki: [Automated data import](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/LANDSAT#Automated_data_import)
- [i.landsat.rgb](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/i.landsat.rgb.html) (or [i.colors.enhance](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/i.colors.enhance.html) in GRASS 7) - auto-enhance colors
- i.landsat.toar (addon for GRASS 6, included in GRASS 7) - convert DN to top of atmosphere radiance
- [i.atcorr](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/i.atcorr.html) - correct top of atmosphere to surface reflectance
- i.landsat.acca (addon) - cloud identification
- i.landsat.dehaze (addon) - haze removal
- [i.landsat.trim](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/AddOns/GRASS_6#i.landsat.trim)  trims the "fringe" from the borders of Landsat images

See also here: http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/LANDSAT

Answer (score 6):

I found this might be useful:

http://ledaps.nascom.nasa.gov/tools/tools.html

The third package is awesome, but never tried with the first one (awaiting respond and permission from the principal).

Answer (score 1):

I have developed an R package (LandsatLinkr), which is an automated system for processing large volumes of Landsat imagery and building spectrally consistent chronologies across MSS, TM, ETM+, and OLI sensors. See the GitHub repo: https://github.com/jdbcode/LandsatLinkr.