# Where can I find a tutorial for installing an addon to GRASS GIS that a six-year-old could understand?

Tags: grass-gis, installation, add-ons

I want to use the r.stream.distance addon in GRASS GIS 6.4 on ubuntu 10.04 (64 bit).

I've installed grass from the repositories and that works fine but I can't seem to figure out how to install this addon (or any other for that matter).

I've tried to run g.extension but I get a "command not found" error.  I've tried to install the addon from svn but the instructions are less than clear to me.

I've read through the documentation on the grass wiki and it seems to assume a lot of knowledge that I seem to lack.

So, does anyone know of a tutorial where I can walk through the steps (baby steps) of installing an addon in grass?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to be at least 13 years of age to be on this site.

Comment: uhhhh... I'm asking for a friend who is 6.

Comment: Today's kids are so smart! I barely knew how to read at 6.

Comment: Too bad Grass doesn't run on Nintendo platform.

Comment: Kirk, maybe just compile it there :)

Comment: Nikos: tell the Ubuntu packagers to package a more recent version...

Comment: I am five times older than your friend and I still dont understand GRASS

Comment: Ragi, check for a beginner's course here: http://geostat-course.org/Topic_NetelerMetz_2011 (material online there)

Answer (score 2):

The much more stable Python version of the extension manager has been [backported](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/changeset/46058/grass/branches/releasebranch_6_4/gui/scripts) to GRASS 6.4.svn five days ago. So, for GRASS 6.4.2 there is a high chance that the Addon installation becomes more easy - integrated in the graphical user interface. We know that it was difficult on some operating systems and work hard to get rid of these problems.

Note for Windows users: At the upcoming [GRASS GIS Community Sprint in Prague](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Community_Sprint_Prague_2011) in May 2011, we will try to autogenerated winGRASS binary addons for easy consumption. Please stay tuned...

Comment: So we did: winGRASS binary Addons are daily created at http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass64/addons/ (installable also through the wxGUI interface in GRASS 6.4.2 or later)

Answer (score 1):

i found this discussion very useful : 
http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/installing-addon-problem-for-regular-users-ubuntu-newbies-td3884021.html#a3885118

Answer (score 0):

Fairly common problem,

http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/g-extension-e-g-to-install-i-landsat-toar-td5662708.html#a5693486

Does running the WinGrass 7 svn help?
http://grass.osgeo.org/download/software.php

Answer (score 0):

See also markusN comment in
[Is there a way to automate the preprocessing of LANDSAT data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/7716/2765)