# How to trim Landsat 5 scene edges

Tags: image-mosaic, landsat, borders

I have a bunch of Landsat 5 scenes that I want to mosaic together.

However Landsat 5 scenes have a zigzag pattern on the left and right edges as well as some bad data values along these edges.

Is there a program that can automatically trim the edges of the Landsat 5 scenes so that all the edges are nice and straight?

Answer (score 7):

You can download the scene boundaries here;

http://landsat.usgs.gov/tools_wrs-2_shapefile.php

You could use these as they are or generate an "inside" buffer shapefile to ensure that you trim all bad data in all bands.

Create a separate file for each scene (use split by attributes tool if there are many images to be processed).

Then clip the rasters (CLIP tool in ArcGIS)

Answer (score 3):

The manual way to do this is to use the official WRS-2 path/row scene boundaries

- Download the [WRS-2 shape file](http://landsat.usgs.gov/documents/wrs2_descending.zip) from USGS’ [Path/Row Shapefiles dedicated web-page](http://landsat.usgs.gov/tools_wrs-2_shapefile.php)
- Select the path/row tile of your interest and use it as a mask to clip border fringes (this might involve rasterising the vector tile)

To answer, however, your question directly about *an automatic way to trim Landsat TM5* (or any other Landsat product I guess) edges, there is [i.landsat.trim](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/AddOns/GRASS_6#i.landsat.trim), a [GRASS-GIS](http://grass.osgeo.org) module.

See also:

- [Is there a way to automate the preprocessing of LANDSAT data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/7717/5256)
- [GRASS-GIS-Wiki page on LANDSAT products](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/LANDSAT)