# How to Remove Dark Bands Where Scenes Overlap in Mosaic Landsat TM5 Image?

Tags: erdas-imagine, landsat, filling

I have an image mosaic of 5 Landsat TM5 scenes. Where the scenes overlap there is a dark band, only on the left and right sides, but the top and bottom are seamless. What is the best way to correct this in Erdas 2011?

Comment: Maybe just trimming away the borders will do the problem away... ? See [How to trim Landsat 5 scene edges](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/34637/5256)

Comment: can you post an image or link to an image?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing the mosaicing, I would suggest using the Mosaic Pro tool and then setting the "Set Overlap Function" (fx icon) to Maximum.  If the overlapping bits are 0 or Null data it will take the highest value, in this case the imagery and exclude the edges.